# Django - Group by and do ArrayAgg

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Deviation(models.Model):
    deviation_number = models.SmallIntegerField()
    day_of_calculation = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

And I'd like to group records of the model by `day_of_calculation` and get list of `deviation_number`s:

```
deviations = Deviation.objects \
    .values('day_of_calculation') \
    .annotate(deviation_numbers=ArrayAgg('deviation_number'))
```

But Django incorrectly creates sql:

```
SELECT "deviation"."day_of_calculation", ARRAY_AGG("deviation"."deviation_number" ) AS "deviation_numbers" FROM "deviation" GROUP BY "deviation"."day_of_calculation", "deviation"."deviation_number"
```

Grouping by `deviation_number` should not happen.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a [**`.order_by(…)`** clause <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) to force a `GROUP BY` on the fields listed in the `.order_by(…)`, so:

```
Deviation.objects.values('day_of_calculation').annotate(
    deviation_numbers=ArrayAgg('deviation_number')
).order_by('day_of_calculation')
```